# InstallData is not running while testing in server

Tags: magento2

Why does it work on local but does not work on server ?

```
<?php
namespace AcountS\AcountStatus\Setup;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;


class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface

{

    private $customerSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(
       CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
) {
      $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
}

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)

    {

        $setup->startSetup();
        /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'account_status', [
            'label' => 'Customer Account Status',
            'input' => 'select',
            'required' => false,
            'sort_order' => 100,
            'visible' => true,
            'system' => false,
            'type' => 'int',
            'source' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Table',
            'is_used_in_grid' => true,
            'is_visible_in_grid' => true,
            'is_filterable_in_grid' => true,
            'is_searchable_in_grid' => true,
            'option' => ['values' => ['Active', 'Suspend', 'Vacations']],
        ]);

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See if the namespace is correct AcountS_AcountStatus (you have a "S" on the AcountS ,not sure if your module is called that way)

Check if the table **AcountS_AcountStatus**  is in database by running .

```
Select * from setup_module;
```

If it isnt there . 
Check if your module is enable

```
php bin/magento module:status
```

If it is enabled than disable temporarly the cache run a

```
php bin/magento cache:disable
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy.
```

If it is there

```
DELETE from setup_module where module = "AcountS_AcountStatus";
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy.
```

Check if it works.